# Finding the nearest point to the centroid of the polygons

Tags: r, sf

I want to find the nearest point/station to the centroid of each polygons.
I have a sf object called `regions` containing 4 polygons and another sf object called `stations_sf` containing station points.

If I plot the points on the polygons, it seems I got a pretty nearest point to the centroid of each polygon (see the image below). However, the problem is that I got the same point `M15` for each of three polygons when I printed `np` in the code below, while I was expecting to get a different point for each of the polygons as many stations are scattered within the polygons.

Any thoughts, please?

I have tried this code:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Points
stations_sf <- st_as_sf(stations, coords = c("X","Y"), crs = "EPSG:24547")
stations_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 57 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 100.1345 ymin: 5.850138 xmax: 100.5273 ymax: 6.448029
#> Projected CRS: Kertau 1968 / UTM zone 47N
#> A tibble: 57 × 2
#>   station_names            geometry
#> * <chr>                 <POINT [m]>
#> 1 M1            (100.1855 6.448029)
#> 2 M2            (100.2407 6.444362)
#> 3 M3            (100.2736 6.418805)
#> 4 M4               (100.1855 6.397)
#> 5 M5            (100.1345 6.397388)
#> 6 M6            (100.1819 6.367528)
#> 7 M7            (100.1604 6.331695)
#> 8 M8            (100.2251 6.364195)
#> 9 M9            (100.2578 6.394555)
#> 10 M10           (100.2044 6.321278)
#> … with 47 more rows
#> ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

# Upload regions
regions <- st_read("spatial data/shapefiles/regions.shp")
regions
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 624748.7 ymin: 640589.5 xmax: 669590.9 ymax: 712757.8
#> Projected CRS: Kertau 1968 / UTM zone 47N
#>   id Regions                       geometry
#> 1  1 Pendang POLYGON ((663163.7 653016.9...
#> 2  2    Arau POLYGON ((644220 708049.7, ...
#> 3  3   Jitra POLYGON ((661188.9 687053.8...
#> 4  4     KSS POLYGON ((650918.4 676399.6...
 
# Find the nearest point to the centroid of the each polygon
np <- st_nearest_feature(st_centroid(regions[2]), stations_sf)
#> Warning message:
#> In st_centroid.sf(regions[2]) :
#>   st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries of x
np
#> [1] 15  3 15 15

regions_nn <- cbind(st_centroid(regions), st_drop_geometry(stations_sf)[np,])
#> Warning message:
#> In st_centroid.sf(regions) :
#>   st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries of x
regions_nn
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 633888.2 ymin: 658659.6 xmax: 660471 ymax: 704745.1
#> Projected CRS: Kertau 1968 / UTM zone 47N
#>   id Regions station_names                  geometry
#> 1  1 Pendang           M15   POINT (660471 671441.7)
#> 2  2    Arau            M3 POINT (633888.2 704745.1)
#> 3  3   Jitra           M15 POINT (645894.4 690930.8)
#> 4  4     KSS           M15 POINT (654007.5 658659.6)

# plot
ggplot() + 
geom_sf(data = regions, fill = 'white') +
geom_sf(data = regions_nn, color = 'red')
```

[image: Image one]

My station data is as follows:

```r
> dput(stations)
structure(list(station_names = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", 
"M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", "M13", "M14", "M15", 
"M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20", "M21", "M22", "M23", "M24", 
"M25", "M26", "M27", "M28", "M29", "M31", "M32", "M33", "M34", 
"M35", "M36", "M37", "M38", "M39", "M40", "M41", "M42", "M43", 
"M44", "M45", "M46", "M47", "M48", "M49", "M50", "M51", "M52", 
"M53", "M54", "M55", "M56", "M57", "M58"), X = c(100.1855, 100.2407, 
100.2736, 100.1855, 100.1345, 100.1819, 100.1604, 100.2251, 100.2578, 
100.2044, 100.2987, 100.2654, 100.2392, 100.2028, 100.3491, 100.3125, 
100.3138, 100.2717, 100.3852, 100.4098, 100.3587, 100.3221, 100.2445, 
100.3388, 100.2961, 100.3196, 100.4039, 100.4679, 100.399, 100.4592, 
100.4662, 100.4809, 100.5273, 100.5106, 100.4298, 100.4464, 100.401, 
100.4445, 100.4756, 100.4447, 100.5108, 100.4715, 100.4113, 100.3676, 
100.3794, 100.3982, 100.3554, 100.3425, 100.3281, 100.2981, 100.3299, 
100.4256, 100.4783, 100.4524, 100.4933, 100.3648, 100.3773), 
    Y = c(6.448029, 6.444362, 6.418805, 6.397, 6.397388, 6.367528, 
    6.331695, 6.364195, 6.394555, 6.321278, 6.369472, 6.328833, 
    6.302028, 6.263695, 6.348555, 6.318388, 6.27875, 6.26625, 
    6.285333, 6.261583, 6.2425, 6.238888, 6.217528, 6.188889, 
    6.180695, 6.151888, 6.200417, 6.222695, 6.149028, 6.175778, 
    6.150695, 6.122556, 6.072555, 6.032722, 6.080333, 6.114805, 
    6.085, 6.023221, 5.993417, 5.973361, 5.971, 5.905638, 6.022528, 
    6.068278, 6.023139, 5.970945, 5.970972, 6.003028, 6.046112, 
    6.107055, 6.097472, 5.914083, 5.865305, 5.866555, 6.032722, 
    5.850138, 5.903083)), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

The link of data for `regions` is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hNrEVt3SuQhMRUyhwC3o6wZodXf9FbBl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just a small remark for the next time asking: Maybe better use the {reprex} package to produce reproducible examples, because code chunks can be copy & pasted seamlessly without the necessity to remove obsolete characters like `>`. Also, it's easier to distinguish between code, output and comments - increasing the probability for someone to reply ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am learning reprex package now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates you provided in `stations` are clearly not projected ones. I'll just assume that they are given in EPSG: 4326 because the range seems plausible for north-western Malaysia. So you need to set a proper definition as a starting point and reproject to EPSG: 24547 subsequently making use of `st_transform()`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)

stations_sf <- st_as_sf(stations, coords = c("X","Y"), crs = "EPSG:4326") |> 
  st_transform("EPSG:24547")

regions <- st_read("regions.shp")

# calc centroids
regions_centr <- st_centroid(regions)
```

So far, the result looks fine, so let's proceed with nearest neighbour estimation:

```r
# find the nearest neighbour to the centroid of the each polygon
stations_nn <- stations_sf[st_nearest_feature(regions_centr, stations_sf),]

# inspect
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = regions, color = 'black') +
  geom_sf(data = stations_sf, color = 'grey') +
  geom_sf(data = regions_centr, color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data = stations_nn, color = 'blue')
```

[image]

Et voilà: Out of all the stations (grey), the nearest stations to your polygon centroids (red), have been correctly identified (blue).

Comment: Thanks for your effort in solving my code problem. The results match what I have found in QGIS software.